# Assembly jumping?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm currently working on the bomb lab and not quite sure what I am missing.

```
 8048db6:   8d 44 24 1c             lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
 8048dba:   89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
 8048dbe:   8d 44 24 18             lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048dc2:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048dc6:   c7 44 24 04 29 a7 04    movl   $0x804a729,0x4(%esp)
 8048dce:   8b 44 24 30             mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
 8048dd2:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048dd5:   e8 26 fb ff ff          call   8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
 8048dda:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 8048ddd:   7f 05                   jg     8048de4 <phase_6+0x31>
 8048ddf:   e8 d1 06 00 00          call   80494b5 <explode_bomb>
 8048de4:   83 7c 24 18 07          cmpl   $0x7,0x18(%esp)
 8048de9:   77 3c                   ja     8048e27 <phase_6+0x74>
 8048deb:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048def:   ff 24 85 18 a5 04 08    jmp    *0x804a518(,%eax,4)
```

Then there's a series of jumps, where they all mov values into %eax, then
jump to 8048e38.

I'm pretty sure I need it to jump since

```
 8048e2c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
```

because there's a cmp and 0x1c(%esp) has value 0 and nothing is ever moved to that address:

```
 8048e38:   3b 44 24 1c             cmp    0x1c(%esp),%eax
 8048e3c:   74 05                   je     8048e43 <phase_6+0x90>
 8048e3e:   e8 72 06 00 00          call   80494b5 <explode_bomb>
 8048e43:   83 c4 2c                add    $0x2c,%esp
 8048e46:   c3                      ret
```

But I'm not sure how to reach that since my input number cannot be greater than 7?

Comment: You need to enter 2 numbers, one of those will be stored at `0x1c(%esp)` so it's only `0` if you enter `0`. You should obviously not do that if the code you omitted can't result in a `0`.

Comment: Wow, that's an embarrassing mistake. Got it, thanks!